# Cisco ip phone set-up

Tags: cisco, configuration, phone

I'm in trouble with my "Cisco IP Phone 7906G". This is the first time i have one of those things in my hands (and in my office). I have another ip phone configured on the network, of course its not a cisco one. My problem is. I have mo idea how to conf it, because on the phone "osd" I have no rights to change the important options.

Of course i havent got a user manual/handbook, or whatever.

So what do i need, or how can i make this phone work?

Comment: Where did it come from? What are you using for your VOIP system? In our network Cisco phones are configured using CallManager servers, so the IT department would have to configure it.

Comment: The phones are configured via a XML file on the DNS assigned (or statically) assigned TFTP server.  CallManager generates these XML files.  But if you are using Asterisk for example you need to create these manually.  Give us some more information...

Comment: The first thing you should probably do is factory reset the phone so that you have full access to the configuration menus. After that, the conf is based on whatever VoIP system you are using. You can find the admin guide for the phone here: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/voice_ip_comm/cuipph/7906g_7911g/6_1_3/english/administration/guide/11troub.html   To factory reset it, see the "Resetting or Restoring the Cisco Unified IP Phone" section.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to download and read http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/voice_ip_comm/cuipph/7906g_7911g/5_1/sccp/english/install/guide/install.html - that should answer your initial questions.